# copy a file to an existing directory but says directory doesnt exit

Tags: csh

i am tryign to copy a file from one directoy that i am to a directory that already exists but the terminal gives me an error saying that it cannot create the file and that it does not exist

```
cp networkset.dat /projects/segra/hallo/data/binet
```

no such file or directory?  this directory exists but why cant i copy this file in a different directory to the one i need it in. I am using c-shell terminal. i know this is trivial but i have tried everything. Do i need to set the directory path permissions?

Comment: Are you sure networkset.dat exists in the crrent dir? Double check permissions on the destination dir.

Comment: yes sir...it certainly does exit. I do a ls-l and i can see it. I checked the permissions on the destination directory and it is drwxrwxr-x    this means i(first three columns) should have read write and execute priviledges correct?

Comment: edit your question with the output of `ls -ld networkset.dat /projects/segra/hallo/data/binet` AND the exact error message you're getting. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination path looks suspiciously like it wants to be off of either your home directory or the current directory, and not from the root. That is, maybe it's supposed to have a "~/" at the beginning?

```
%if /projects is in your home dir
cp networkset.dat ~/projects/segra/hallo/data/binet
```

or

```
%if /projects is off of the current directory
cp networkset.dat ./projects/segra/hallo/data/binet
```